# Write the value of a dictionary to a string, where there are multiple items associated with value

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, key, tostring

I was wondering if it is possible to write both the dictionary key and all records associated with the value to string?

However i only get the output of the Key and one item in value (service status)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just modify your ToString overload.

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return "Display Name = " & _displayName & ", Service Name = " & _serviceName & ", Status = " & _serviceStatus
End Function
```

And, if you need ToString to only return the status, then move the above code into a new function (say DisplayValue) and modify your loop to use this instead of ToString:

```
sbService.AppendLine(item.Key & "| " & item.Value.DisplayValue)
```